# Gmapping outputs wrong map in tutorials

Tags: slam, navigation, hector, hokuyo, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed the tutorials at the page of hector slam
but the final map seems not right, you can find my map at  [www.dropbox.com/s/9072yf1f41nk18e/capture.png](http://www.dropbox.com/s/9072yf1f41nk18e/capture.png)

Are there any other parameters I need to set?

I also use the bag "Team_Hector_MappingBox_RoboCup_2011_Rescue_Arena.bag" in gmapping following its tutorials

Also got the wrong map.

What should I do to solve this problem?
What's more, how to generate a map simultaneously without a bag file?I just have a notebook and a hokuyo laser scanner(ulg-04lx), can any one give me a tutorial?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/169576/gmapping-outputs-wrong-map-in-tutorials/) by [zxh362989](https://answers.ros.org/users/18461/zxh362989/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-05-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The example bagfile we provide won´t work with gmapping as I don´t provide odometry data while walking ;) , which gmapping requires. Please edit your post with details such as

- computer type
- operating system (e.g.    Ubuntu
  12.04 64 Bit or so)
- information on how you installed  hector_slam (from .debs or compiled
  yourself)

I suspect that for some reason things run too slow, so the mapping process can´t keep up with the incoming data. This can happen when accidentally building code without optimization using catkin (see further info [here](https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_slam/issues/11)) and/or when running the system on a very slow CPU.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-05-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zxh362989](https://answers.ros.org/users/18461/zxh362989/) on 2014-05-26**:
My notebok is Thinkpad X201 with Ubuntu 13.04.
I installed hector_slam just as the tutorials(sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-hector-slam)
When I run the bag, I checked out the CPU status, it consumes about 9% of CPU. What can I do in the next step?
And what should I do if I want to generate a map without a bag file, just with my notebook and laser scanner.
Thank you for your reply!